# C using malloc and free correctly in a program I wrote

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, valgrind, free

In a course I take, there's a pset that involves reading a dictionary file, and creating a hash-table out of it, checking the correct spelling of words in another file by means of checking whether a word in text can be found in the hashtable. Then unloading it from memory.

There are two files in the program. One file that I didn't write (and has no problems for sure), that runs first and calls the functions of the .c file that I wrote:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

#define DICSIZE 10000

typedef struct node
{

    char* word;
    struct node* next;

} 
node;

typedef struct table
{
    node** table;
    unsigned int wordCount;
}
table;

// initialize table for scope purposes
struct table* hashTable = NULL;

// declaration of the hash function
unsigned long hashDJB2(unsigned char *str);
// declaration of the string duplication function
char* mystrdup(const char* s);
// declaration of the lowercase function
char* returnLowerCase(const char* str);

/**
 * Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
 */
bool check(const char* word)
{
    node* list = NULL;
    char* wrd = returnLowerCase(word);
    unsigned long hashValue = hashDJB2((unsigned char*) wrd);
    for (list = hashTable->table[hashValue]; list != NULL; list = list->next) {

        if (strcmp(list->word, wrd) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    free(wrd);
    return false;
}

/**
 * Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{

    // allocation of memory for the table structure
    if ((hashTable = malloc(sizeof(struct table))) == NULL) {

        printf("Error allocating memory for table pointer\n");
        return false;

    }

    // allocate pointers to table itself
    if ((hashTable->table = malloc((sizeof(node*) * DICSIZE) + sizeof(unsigned int))) == NULL) {

        printf("Error allocating memory for heads of list\n");
        return false;

    }

    // initialize head nodes to NULL
    for (int i = 0; i < DICSIZE; i++) {

        hashTable->table[i] = NULL;
    }

    // initialize wordCount to zero
    hashTable->wordCount = 0;

    /*
    * Till now, was the creation of the backbone structure.
    * Now, implementation of hash() function and loading the words
    * onto the table.
    */ 

    FILE* dp;
    dp = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    if (dp == NULL) {
        printf("Error in reading from dictionary\n");
        return false;
    }

    // reading words from dictionary
    char newWord[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(dp, "%s", newWord) == 1) {


        // determine the hash value of the 
        unsigned long hashValue = hashDJB2((unsigned char*) newWord);

        // in the pset, they say i don't have to check whether the word already exists
        // if (! check((const char*) newWord)) {

            // if not, insert a new node:

            // attempt to create a new node
            node* newNode = NULL;
            if ((newNode = malloc(sizeof(node))) == NULL) {

                printf("Error: couldnt allocate a new node\n");
                return false;
            }

            // insert new node to the beginning of the list
            newNode->word = mystrdup(newWord);
            newNode->next = hashTable->table[hashValue];
            hashTable->table[hashValue] = newNode;
            hashTable->wordCount++;

        //}
    }    
    //free(dp);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
 */
unsigned int size(void)
{

    unsigned int wordCount = hashTable->wordCount;
    return wordCount;
}

/**
 * Unloads dictionary from memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool unload(void)
{

    node* head = NULL;
    long i = 0;
    for (head = hashTable->table[i]; head != NULL; head = hashTable->table[++i]) {

        node* list = NULL;
        for (list = head; list != NULL; list = head) {

            head = head->next;
            free(list->word);
            free(list);
        }
    }
    free(hashTable->table);
    free(hashTable);
    return true;
}

// djb2 algorithm, created by Dan Bernstein
unsigned long hashDJB2(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while ((c = *str++))
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash % DICSIZE;
}

char* mystrdup(const char* s)
{
    char* p = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(s)+1);
    if (p) strcpy(p, s);
    return p;
}

char* returnLowerCase(const char* str) {

    int len = strlen(str);
    char* p = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        p[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    }
    p[len + 1] = '\0'; // this line made the program crash. It was fixed already.

    return p;
}
```

First the "speller.c" (which I got from the pset) calls the load() function, then calls the check() function several tens of thousands times (depends on the number of words in the text), then unload(). I have a problem with the checking and unloading part. When the text is small the check() functions properly, but when It gets larger I get an error like this:

> speller: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

The first problem is, It seems that there is a problem in the way I allocate memory. The other problem is that I don't manage to free all the memory I've allocated.

For some reason, valgrinds --track-origins=yes doesn't work so all I've got from It is this:

```
==3852== 
==3852== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3852==     in use at exit: 101,650 bytes in 18,547 blocks
==3852==   total heap usage: 305,376 allocs, 286,829 frees, 2,730,448 bytes allocated
==3852== 
==3852== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3852==    definitely lost: 101,298 bytes in 18,546 blocks
==3852==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3852==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3852==    still reachable: 352 bytes in 1 blocks
==3852==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3852== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3852== 
==3852== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3852== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==3852== ERROR SUMMARY: 57191 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I would love to get some help at that.

Comment: After the user  Paul R commented on the "p[len + 1] = '\0';", I've fixed It, and the program stopped crashing. Also, I've added 'free(wrd)' in the check() function before returning true after finding a word in the dictionary. This results in only 1 error from 1 context, and a memory leak of 352 bytes in 1 block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One bug (there may be others), in `returnLowerCase()`:

```
p[len + 1] = '\0';
```

should be:

```
p[len] = '\0';
```

(You have allocated `len + 1` chars, so the valid indices are `0..len` inclusive, with the actual string being at indices `0..len-1` and the `\0` terminator at index `len`.)

Comment: OMG, Thanks! This saved my program from crashing while check() was called. Now all that remains is freeing memory correctly.